# Laws of Logic Expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Going through yet another practice exam and I'm stumped on the below question. Any help is appreciated.

What laws were used to reduce this:

$E = x\cdot (x+y)\cdot \overline{y}$

to this:

$E = x\cdot\overline{y}$

Answer (score 3):

It is always true that $x \cdot x = x$ (idempotence), $x \cdot \bar{x} = 0$ (complementation), $x\cdot 0=0$ (anihilation), and $x+0=x$ (identity).

Then by distribution and the above : $x(x+y) \bar{y} ~{= x \cdot x \cdot \bar{y} + x \cdot y \cdot \bar{y} \\ = x \cdot \bar{y}}$.

Comment: sorry man i should have been more clear, i meant laws such as distributive, de morgan etc..

Comment: Laws smell as sweet by any other name...

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $x\cdot(x+y)=x$ is called Absorption, which is a basic law of logic

In the event that Absorption was not provided to you, here is Absorption derived from other basic rules:

$$x\cdot(x+y) \overset{Identity}= (x+0)\cdot (x+y)\overset{Distribution}=x+0\cdot y\overset{Annihilation}= x+0 \overset{Identity}= x$$

Comment: Are there a couple of terms missing in the Distribution step?

Comment: @IanF1 No, it's correct, though it's probably easier to recognize as an instance of distribution if you start with the right side and go to the left. From left to right, it feels more like 'un-distribution' or 'reverse distribution' or 'collect common terms'